# Dragging event reverts before confirm

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a calendar with drag functionality where a user can drag events to quickly update them.

After Dragging an event I ask the user if he wants to save it and then call a UpdatEvent function.

However, before the user confirms, (just as the dialog appears)  the event automatically reverts back and only return to the updated position if I confirm in the dialog.

Is there a way for the event to stay in the dragged position and then either revert back or stay in the actual one?

My eventDrop looks like this:

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
if (confirm("Do you wish to save the event?")) {
UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start);
}
else {
revertFunc();
}
}
```

Comment: I know the topic is old, but I've been through the same problem.
What about using [jQuery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) to show a popup? This won't cause this undesirable visual effect.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the Eventdrop and/or Eventresize place the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
```